# Can the environment code is running in cause variable values to change unexpectedly in a loop?

Tags: java, android, string, image, memory

Can the memory resources of a phone make code behave unexpectedly? The code below behaves correctly in some phones, but incorrectly in others.

```
//array is an input of 2500 doubles

int[] array_of_items_times_my_var = new int[2500];

double my_var=10;
if ( my_string.equals(“first_string”) )
    my_var=1; //selected case
else if ( my_string.equals("second_string") )
    my_var=100;

double [] array_of_averages = new double[100];

System.out.println("my_var="+my_var); //prints 1.0 correctly.

for (int i=0; i<2500; i++) { 

    System.out.println("my_var="+my_var); 
    //prints 1.0 correctly up to i~=2147; 
    //after i~=2148, it prints 0.0 INcorrectly.

    array_of_items_times_my_var[i]=(int)Math.round(array[i]*my_var);
    currentAverageBeingCalculated+=array[i];
    numberOfElementsUsedToObtainCurrentAverage++;

    // more code to update array_of_averages without using "my_var"
}

System.out.println("my_var="+my_var); //prints 0.0 INcorrectly.
```

Comment: The value of `my_var` does not change in the loop so, System.out.println("my_var="+my_var);` should always print the same value.

Comment: @Scary I agree; and that's the way it behaves with small phones; but this LG Stylo 4 of 6 inches behaves unexpectedly; the variable changes. Could it be that as `array_of_items_times_my_var` gets updated, if memory is scarce, `my_var` gets a value of 0?

Comment: @Scary Can I make another post? Asking: "Can the memory resources of a phone make code behave unexpectedly? The code below behaves correctly in some phones, but incorrectly in others."

Comment: I'll just answer that here: no, the amount of memory in a phone should not have an effect like that.

Comment: @Ryan M Respectfully, I think this could be something worth looking at. I have been doing lots of tests. I included LogCat from tests in a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60894130/android-cache-affecting-value-of-variable